# Custom adapter not displaying text in listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have recently started programming for android. I am writing a simple customadapter class in an app. The problem is that the adapter is not displaying any text in the listview. The logcat shows no error messages, but still the app is not working as expected.

I am including snippets of my code files for reference-

Reportcard.java

```
package com.example.jsk.myreportcard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Reportcard extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reportcard);    

        ArrayList<Result>s=new ArrayList<Result>();    

        s.add(new Result("Science","A")); s.add(new Result("Maths","A"));     

        ReportAdapter adapter=new ReportAdapter(this, s);
        ListView l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
       l.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Result.java

```
package com.example.jsk.myreportcard;


public class Result  {

  private   String subject,grade;

    public Result(String subjec, String grad)
    {
        subjec=subject;
        grad=grade;
    }

    public String getSubject()
    {
        return subject;
    }
    public String getGrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }

}
```

ReportAdapter.java

```
package com.example.jsk.myreportcard;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ReportAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Result> {

    public ReportAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Result>w) {
        super(context, 0, w);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v=convertView;
        if(v==null)
        {
           v= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lay_text,parent,false);
        }

        Result res=getItem( position);
        TextView sub=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        sub.setText(res.getSubject());
        TextView grad=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.t2);
        grad.setText(res.getGrade());

//        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return v;
    }


}
```

Now the layout files-

reportcard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

lay_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/lay">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        tools:text="hello"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        tools:text="World"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me to get this app working .
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning values in constructor , you are assigning default values of `Stings` i.e `null` to local variable `subjec` and `grad`

```
public Result(String subjec, String grad)
{
    subjec=subject; //  yourvalue = null
    grad=grade;     //  yourvalue = null
}
```

should be

```
public Result(String subjec, String grad)
{
    subject=subjec; //  datafield = yourvalue
    grade=grad;     //  datafield = yourvalue
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Dont know why I did something so stupid like that.

Comment: @Backspace don't discourage yourself , it happens with many pro guys too , keep it up and happy coding

Comment: although you can do this `public Result(String subject, String grade)` and use assignment like `this.subject=subject` and `this.grade=grade`

Comment: Yes, I am quite familiar with that concept, but somehow I missed it while writing the app.